# Fiber bundles, orientation preserving map and pushforwards

Tags: probability-theory, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, fiber-bundles

I am reading an article about the geometric foundation of Hamiltonian Markov Chain Monte Carlo (see https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-23/issue-4A/The-geometric-foundations-of-Hamiltonian-Monte-Carlo/10.3150/16-BEJ810.full) and I stumbled upon some lines which to my knowledge don't make sense. I would appreciate any clarifications on my potential misunderstanding.

From the paper:

> A smooth fiber bundle, $\omega : Z \mapsto Q$, combines an $(n + k)$-dimensional total space, Z, an $n$-dimensional base space, $Q$, and a smooth projection, $\omega$ , that **injectively** maps, or submerses, the total space into the base space.

Question: I think it should be a surjective map not an injective. Is that correct?

Next part:

> We will refer to a positively-oriented fiber bundle as a fiber
> bundle in which both the total space and the base space are positively-oriented and the projection operator is orientation-preserving

Question: How can the projection map be orientation preserving if the dimensionality of both spaces differ? I think orientation preserving maps are only possible for local diffeomorphisms.

Next part:

> ... while horizontal vector fields, X˜i, push forward to the tangent space of the base space

Again: pushforwards are - to the best of my knowledge - only defined for diffeomorphisms.

And finally:

> Formally, volume forms are defined as positive, top-rank differential forms,
> $M(Q) = \{ \mu \in \Omega^n(Q)| \mu_q > 0, \forall \in Q \}$

What is the meaning of $\mu_q>0$. If I read it pointwise it doesn't make sense: How can a n-form be pointwise positive? If it is positive for a particular set of tangent vectors $v_1, \dots v_n$, then it will be negative, when using $-v_1, v_2, \dots v_n$.

Comment: I believe a positive $n$-form on an $n$-dimensional oriented manifold is one where in oriented coordinates it has the form $f dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n$ where $f > 0$. The classic example is the volume form $\sqrt{g}dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n$ on a Riemannian Manifold.

Comment: If some author wrote "injectively maps, or submerses," I would not trust anything in that author's writing henceforth.  Your first two assertions are correct. However, any smooth map has a push-forward map on tangent spaces. And the author's last claim *is* correct. An orientation on a vector space tells you that ordered bases are either "positive" or "negative"; a top-degree form is positive precisely when its value on any positively-oriented basis is positive (at each point of the manifold).

Comment: @Mason That assumes that $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is a positively-oriented chart.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes that is what I meant by "oriented coordinates".

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I missed that. @Mason

Comment: many thanks. But one last question: @ted shifrin: I still don't understand what $\mu_p>0$ is supposed to indicate: That is, for an alternating n-tensor $\omega$: what is the meaning of $\omega>0$?

Comment: That was my last sentence. Mason answered that, as well.